# Firestore AdminSDK retry timeout

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a node server using the admin sdk to listen for changes on documents and then write to a log.  I get these errors after 5 - 10 minutes of running.

```
(node:1088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Retry total timeout exceeded before any response was received
    at repeat (C:\connect2sql\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\api_callable.js:215:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\connect2sql\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\api_callable.js:243:25)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

Any ideas how to extend the timeout or speed up google-gax?

Comment: Where are you running your Node server?

Comment: Are you able to receive any data initially? I am unable to reproduce the issue when running locally, which is why I asked what server you're using.

Comment: @JenPerson I was running on heroku and now I am running on a dedicated VM in azure (windows server 2016).  Yes, I receive initial data for about 5 - 10 minutes then the log fills up with these retry timeouts.

Comment: @JenPerson node version 8.12.0 firebase admin version  6

Comment: We are having same issue now...

Comment: Did anyone solve this? Or find any workaround?

Comment: @JaynaTanawala unfortunately no, we ended up scrapping using nodejs and switched to .net (using .net adminsdk firestore). This has worked for us very well.